# How to create material texture using file api in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to build a model browser which users can select model and texture themselves.So I use File API.
I use two file input to receive model and texture.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".obj" />
    <input type="file" name="texture" id="texture" accept=".jpg" />
</form>
```

and add two events:

```
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
document.getElementById('texture').addEventListener('change', readTexture, false);
```

Here is the functions:
s

```
function readFile(evt) {
if(window.object) {                     
        scene.remove(object);
        delete object;
}
var fileObject = evt.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(fileObject);

reader.onload = function() {
loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
object = loader.parse(reader.result);
scene.add(object);
};
}//add model to scene

function readTexture(evt) {
  if(window.mat){
   scene.remove(mat);
   delete mat;
  }
  var fileObject = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject);
  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
  mat.map=reader.result;//error,it doesn’t works.

  reader.onload = function() {
  object.children[0].material = mat;
};
}//add texture to model
```

I know 'mat.map=reader.resul't could't work correctly,but I don't know how to do.
Anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load(reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject));
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:texture});
```

untested

Comment: 3Q.I have solve it and have answered my question but It seems that my answer disapperaed......I use blob URL replace resource url and it works fine.